# Can't shut gate valve leading to hose bib

Tags: plumbing

No surprise here, lack of use and age has kept this valve (pictured) in the open position. Certainly not going to brute force it because we know how that will play out. Since the basement is somewhat heated (Central NJ), should I really be concerned about closing this valve which leads to the exterior hose bib?

The distance from the valve to the exterior wall is in excess of 3 ft which is unreachable by anyone with normal length arms, making this additionally challenging and ultimately, I want to swap this out with a ball valve, but just not when it's 10 degrees outside with a burst pipe.

Thoughts on best way to approach in the short, and long-term? Or just do nothing since the house is 60 years old, or which I've been here 7 and it's gone this long seemingly without issues.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of hose bib is it?  Need a picture of that.

Comment: Thanks.. added picture. This thing clearly needs to be replaced as well as more water sprays out of the handle than makes it through the hose!

Comment: The outside is not a frost free valve.  In theory, the inside should be closed and drained for winter.  Except as you say, it hasn’t been a problem for many years (it took more than 7 for that valve to get stuck open).  When it can be replaced, replace it with a frost free valve outside and eliminate or forget the inside valve.